# Choosing a ‘proper’ function for ‘almost everywhere coset’

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

I have a question about ‘almost-everywhere’.

I learned that in lebesgue-measure, we consider all (f=0 a.e) functions as a same function.
In this view, we can choose a function for each coset (for same functions almost everywhere).

I know we can choose one function for each coset, but if we really need to choose the exact function, what would be the best definition? (I know the word ‘best’ is not a good term, but I don’t have any idea to explain it in mathematical way.)

For example, we should choose f=0 for {f=0 a.e}.
And if we can choose continuous function, we should choose it.
And if it there is a piecewise continuous function, we should choose the one that is (1) left-continuous or (2) right-continuous. (Anything would be okay, but anyway we should choose one standard.)
And for a general coset... what(or how?) should i choose?

I want to construct this like we construct the ‘measure’ starting from open interval, then open set, than measurable set.

I guess there must be mathematical theory for this, but I don’t even know how to search... so please help.

Thank you so much, and sorry for my bad english.

I’ll really appreciate for any comments related to this. Thank you.

Comment: I think that this choice should be motivated: what is the purpose of this choice? If you have a clear purpose in mind, you can define what you need.

Comment: Anyway, for locally integrable functions $f$, you can choose $$F(x) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\mu (B(x, r))} \int_{|y-x|<r} f(y) \mathrm \ d  \mu (y)$$ which is a.e. equal to $f$.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for the advice and answer. After looking your comment, I realized that I don’t know what I wanted to know.
My thoughts are oriented from ‘fat cantour set’. I understanded characteristic function for cantour set as a f=0 except few sparse points(although points are dense set of [0,1]), since cantour set is measure 0.
Then, if we construct a characteristic function for fat cantour set (constructed by deleting 1/4 of remained interval for each step), is there a function that is ‘more intuitive’? This was my motivation, though it is very rough.
(Continue)

Comment: @Crostul
Well I think I need to think a lot more to continue this discussion, cause my idea does not contains some great ideas until now on. Your advice was really helpful, and your answer is almost the one that I was wondering. I really appreciate you. Thank you!